# Who do I meet with to offer my resignation?

Tags: professionalism, resignation, quitting

I am currently working an internship at a small (13 person, including me) US company. When I started this internship it was fairly informal, with no real contract or defined length. The company doesn't actually have an HR person.

Now I have accepted an offer from another company and need to offer my resignation, but I'm not sure who to talk to.

There are 3 possible choices as I see it:

1. **The project manager.** He oversees my day-to-day activities, and in the past has provided me feedback on my performance and how likely it was that I would be offered a position "after" my internship. He is one of two people that I have to notify if I need time off work. He is also the lead when it comes to hiring new people.
2. **The guy that processes paychecks.** He is technically the CFO of the company. He handles all the paychecks and had me fill out my starting paperwork. He is the other person I have to notify if I am taking time off work. However, I have seen no other signs that he deals with employees at all and I don't interact with him much.
3. **The guy who has talked about arranging when they would make me a post internship offer.** Technically, this guy is the CTO of the company. However, he is the only person who has mentioned a timeline of when I would be made an offer after my internship. When I started, he was the one in charge of setting up all of my accounts and such with the company and has a role in deciding who gets to transition their internships into actual positions.

Setting up a meeting with all 3 would be difficult, and I don't want to waste people's time if they have nothing to do with it. I'm considering just sending an email to all 3 at once, but I know it is preferable to give notice in person initially.

So my question is in two parts:
1. Given the lack of clarity, should I arrange a meeting to discuss this in person, or email all the possible people at once?
2. If I should arrange an in-person meeting, who do you think I should meet with?

Comment: Please do not post answers in the comments

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From what you've posted I would suggest going with either the CTO or your Project Manager. Given your PM handles leave requests etc (and is the person who would feel the most immediate effects of your resignation in terms of planning workload etc) I think they would be the right person to go to in the first instance. If they feel that they have insufficient authority in the company then they should be able to direct you to the most appropriate person but as your day-to-day point of contact it feels to me that they are the correct choice.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest is to meet with the person who does the most work managaging what you do, tell them that you wish to resign, and ask who should get the resignation. That person would probably be your project manager; it's also good to inform them because they are most affected by this, and most likely to make you change your mind if they choose to do so.

Legally fine but not very nice is finding the legal address of the company, and send a registered letter to that address. That's what you would have to do if your PM is on a four week holiday, and the CEO is on a four week business trip, and you want to leave in two weeks.